# Compilar código c++ com o make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, make

Estou tentando compilar um projeto em c++ utilizando o seguinte código makefile:

```
OBJS        = main.o src.o
SDIR        = ./src
IDIR        = ./include
BDIR        = ./bin/
ODIR        = $(BDIR)/obj


all: main

%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp $(IDIR)/%.h
    g++ -c -o $(ODIR)/$@ $(SDIR)/$<  -I $(IDIR)

main: $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $@ $^ -I $(IDIR)
```

Quando tento compilar o programa aparece o seguinte erro no terminal:

```
xxxx@zzz:$ make
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
main.cpp:2:17: fatal error: src.h: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
 #include "src.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Mas o arquivo 'src.h' existe e está dentro da basta include. Então gostaria de saber qual o motivo do erro.

Answer (score 1):

Como os seus .obj ficam em um subdiretório você precisa adicionar esse subdiretório como um prefixo:

```
OBJS        = $(addprefix $(ODIR)/, main.o src.o)
```

A regra também precisa usar o subdiretório:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp $(IDIR)/%.h
```

No final o makefile fica assim:

```
SDIR        = ./src
IDIR        = ./include
BDIR        = ./bin
ODIR        = $(BDIR)/obj
OBJS        = $(addprefix $(ODIR)/, main.o src.o)

all: main

$(ODIR)/%.o: $(SDIR)/%.cpp $(IDIR)/%.h
    g++ -c -o $@ $<  -I $(IDIR)

main: $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $@ $^ -I $(IDIR)
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro esta indicando que o erro esta acontecendo durante a compilação do arquivo `main.cpp`. Por agora não tem nenhuma evidência que o problema esteja no makefile criado.

O `main.cpp` está tentando incluir o arquivo `src.h` na compilação, mas esse não está sendo encontrado. Considerando a declaração:

```
#include "src.h"
```

O compilador vai tentar buscar esse arquivo na mesma pasta em que o `main.cpp` esta salvo.

Não sei em que pasta o `main.cpp` está salvo, assumo que seja na pasta `/src`. Acredito também que o `src.h` esteja salvo na pasta `/include`.

É necessário alterar o `#include` com o caminho exato do arquivo `src.h`.

Algo do tipo:

```
#include "../include/src.h"
```

Note que essa é a resposta levando em considereção as coisas que assumi antes.
O importante é que o dentro do teu `main.cpp` (e qualquer outro arquivo .cpp que inclua algo do `/include`) o caminho completo esteja definido.